# How to make custom control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

In winforms there were 2 templates: `UserControl` allows to make composite control (group of existing controls) to reuse it and standardize operations with it, `CustomControl` was a fully custom control (often rendered manually, performing differently than standard controls, etc), allowing overriding and provides access to `protected` things.

In wpf I only found `UserControl` template (using express edition of VS).

To create custom `MyControl` I am doing following:

- create normal class, based on `Control`/`ContentControl`;
- create resource dictionary with `Style` containing control template (could be only `ControlTemplate`, style is better, because can contain other properties setter)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MySolution">
    <Style x:Key="MyControl" TargetType="local:MyControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyControl">
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_Grid">
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

- *bind* them together like this

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        var dictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
        dictionary.Source = new Uri("/MySolution;component/MyControl.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        Style = dictionary["MyControl"] as Style;
        Loaded += MyControl_Loaded;
    }
}
```

- define *lazy* parts accessors in template

```
private Grid _partGrid;
private Grid PartGrid
{
    get
    {
        if (_partGrid == null)
            _partGrid = (Grid)Template.FindName("PART_Grid", this);
        return _partGrid;
    }
}
```

It works, but I am not sure if its the most optimal way:

- `.cs` and `.xaml` are separate files (not one *entity* as in case of wpf `UserControl`);
- when moving `xaml` (to example, inside `Controls` folder) constructor code has to be adjusted;
- parts accessor are not available in constructor (template is yet not loaded).

**My question: is there better way to make custom control with template?** More comfortable, automatic, with automatic parts accessors, etc.

---

Here are my wpf templates

[image]

Comment: There is a custom control template. Also a template for control library. Dunno about Express but kinda expect it to be there.

Comment: @JohanLarsson, see edit, I see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh738343.aspx) on screenshot there is `Templated Control`, but I don't have it. There is no online template with such name either. Does my question become "how to get templated control for express edition"? Does it solves issues I listed? Also, you say "control library", I've only "class library" (as a new project) does it matter?

Comment: @Sinatr it might indeed be express related. i used to test things in express too, which lacked some pretty vital templates. might be the case here too.

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you use the CustomControl VS template, not sure why you don't see it, maybe because you are using the Express version. That template generates a Generic.xaml file for you, there you define the styles/controltemplate. Also you will have the .cs with the c# definition of your control.

To get the diferent parts of your control, the recommended way is using the GetTemplateChild mehtod and pass the Part_Name and you normally do that overriding the OnApplyTemplate() method.

```
 public override void OnApplyTemplate()
  {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    ActionBtn = GetTemplateChild(BtnPartName) as ButtonBase;
    ContentPopup = GetTemplateChild(PopupPartName) as Popup;
  }
```

Take a look to [this post](https://csharpvault.com/blog/wpf-template-parts/) to check a sample with the details of that implementation.